# Vector Push_Back VS Emplace_Back

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector, vulkan

I have two different methods for adding elements to a vector.

```
GUI_Vertices.emplace_back();

GUI_Vertices.back().pos.x = ((float)x / 400) - 1.f;
GUI_Vertices.back().pos.y = ((float)y / 300) - 1.f;
GUI_Vertices.back().texCoord.x = u;
GUI_Vertices.back().texCoord.y = v;
GUI_Vertices.back().color.r = m_Color.r / 128;
GUI_Vertices.back().color.g = m_Color.g / 128;
GUI_Vertices.back().color.b = m_Color.b / 128;
GUI_Vertices.back().color.a = m_Color.a / 128;
```

The above code works, however I am forced to add a new element to the `GUI_Vertices` vector.

```
Vertex NewVertex;

NewVertex.pos.x = ((float)x / 400) - 1.f;
NewVertex.pos.y = ((float)y / 300) - 1.f;
NewVertex.texCoord.x = u;
NewVertex.texCoord.y = v;
NewVertex.color.r = m_Color.r / 128;
NewVertex.color.g = m_Color.g / 128;
NewVertex.color.b = m_Color.b / 128;
NewVertex.color.a = m_Color.a / 128;

GUI_Vertices.emplace_back(NewVertex);
```

The above code works *sometimes* and I can conditionally add the `NewVertex` into the `GUI_Vertices` vector if needed.

Here is the definition of `Vertex`:

```
struct Vertex {
    glm::vec3 pos;
    glm::vec4 color;
    glm::vec2 texCoord;

    static VkVertexInputBindingDescription getBindingDescription() {
        VkVertexInputBindingDescription bindingDescription = {};
        bindingDescription.binding = 0;
        bindingDescription.stride = sizeof(Vertex);
        bindingDescription.inputRate = VK_VERTEX_INPUT_RATE_VERTEX;

        return bindingDescription;
    }

    static std::array<VkVertexInputAttributeDescription, 3> getAttributeDescriptions() {
        std::array<VkVertexInputAttributeDescription, 3> attributeDescriptions = {};

        attributeDescriptions[0].binding = 0;
        attributeDescriptions[0].location = 0;
        attributeDescriptions[0].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32_SFLOAT;
        attributeDescriptions[0].offset = offsetof(Vertex, pos);

        attributeDescriptions[1].binding = 0;
        attributeDescriptions[1].location = 1;
        attributeDescriptions[1].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_SFLOAT;
        attributeDescriptions[1].offset = offsetof(Vertex, color);

        attributeDescriptions[2].binding = 0;
        attributeDescriptions[2].location = 2;
        attributeDescriptions[2].format = VK_FORMAT_R32G32_SFLOAT;
        attributeDescriptions[2].offset = offsetof(Vertex, texCoord);

        return attributeDescriptions;
    }

    bool operator==(const Vertex& other) const {
        return pos == other.pos && color == other.color && texCoord == other.texCoord;
    }
};

namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<Vertex> {
        size_t operator()(Vertex const& vertex) const {
            return ((hash<glm::vec3>()(vertex.pos) ^
                (hash<glm::vec4>()(vertex.color) << 1)) >> 1) ^
                (hash<glm::vec2>()(vertex.texCoord) << 1);
        }
    };
}
```

Later on in program execution, after adding all our `Vertex` elements to the `GUI_Vertex` vector I perform the following operation on `GUI_Vertex`:

```
memcpy(GUI_VertexAllocation->GetMappedData(), GUI_Vertices.data(), sizeof(Vertex) * GUI_Vertices.size());
```

I'm copying the memory from `GUI_Vertices` into a preallocated buffer which will be used by Vulkan to render our vertices.

Now i'm trying to figure out why the first method of adding `Vertex` objects into `GUI_Vertices` always works and the second method only sometimes works.

Here is a link to the entire project https://github.com/kklouzal/WorldEngine/blob/GUI_Indirect_Draw/Vulkan/VulkanGWEN.hpp

After recompiling the project the second method will occasionally work so I'm getting some undefined behavior here. I have checked the validity of `GUI_Vertices` up until the point where we do our `memcpy` and the data appears to be valid so I'm not sure whats going on.

I would like to get the second method working so I can conditionally add new vertices into the buffer.

Comment: What happens when it does not work?

Comment: @TanveerBadar It would just draw blank on the screen as if no vertex data was copied during `memcpy`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ```
> NewVertex.pos.x = ((float)x / 400) - 1.f;
> NewVertex.pos.y = ((float)y / 300) - 1.f;
> ...
> glm::vec3 pos;
> ```

`emplace_back` will always perform value initialization on the object it creates, which initializes all of the data members. By contrast, `Vertex NewVertex;` will default-initialize the object, which leaves its members uninitialized (since the GLM types have trivial default constructors).

So `pos.z` is uninitialized. And your code doesn't initialize it yourself. So you're sending uninitialized garbage to the GPU.

If you create the object with `Vertex NewVertex{};`, then it will be value-initialized, just like `emplace_back` does.